# Certificate Information Exported to CSV is Empty using Different Credential

Tags: arrays, powershell, certificate, export-to-csv

I have an array that I write certificate information into using a credential called `$array_otheruser` but when I try to `Export-Csv`, the file becomes empty.

However, it writes fine if my export line is within the `$ScriptBlock`. However, I want to export it out of scriptblock, is this possible?

The code below writes an empty file:

```
[string][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]$passwd = "password"
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $passwd -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential ("username", $secpasswd)

$array_otheruser = @()
$CSVFile = "c:\temp\temp9.csv"
$Certs = Get-ChildItem Cert: -Recurse

[ScriptBlock]$ScriptBlock = {
    $Certs | where {
        $_.PsIsContainer -eq $false
    } | ForEach-Object ({
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "NotAfter" -Value $_.NotAfter
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "NotBefore" -Value $_.NotBefore
        $array_otheruser += $obj

        $obj = $null
    })
}

$otheruser = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -ComputerName $env:computername -Credential $mycreds | Wait-Job

$otheruser | Receive-Job

$array_otheruser | Export-Csv -Path $CSVFile -NoTypeInformation
```

The code below writes into the file (where I've put the `Export-Csv` inside the scriptblock):

```
[ScriptBlock]$ScriptBlock = {
    ...
        $array_otheruser += $obj
        $obj = $null
    })

    ##########This is the key difference, the export line is inside the ScriptBlock
    $array_otheruser | Export-Csv -Path "c:\temp\temp9.csv" -NoTypeInformation
    ########
}

$otheruser = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -ComputerName $env:computername -Credential $mycreds | Wait-Job

$otheruser | Receive-Job
```

I would like to know if it is possible to have the `Export-Csv` file line outside of the scriptblock and have the cert information contents populate as it should using a different credential.

Comment: from what i can tell, your scriptblock never outputs _anything_. [*grin*] it needs to output the collection if you want the collection to be available outside the scriptblock.

Comment: So the ScriptBlock does work if I have the export-csv line inside it (second block of code). However, when I move it out of the ScriptBlock (first block of code), it doesn't work.

Comment: I didn't want to write the whole code again for the second code block, but I can do that if you want me to. That one writes to CSV file with the contents I want.

Comment: You're running the command synchronously anyway, so there's no need for using a background-job-like approach in the first place. Just output `$obj` in the scriptblock without appending to an array, and run `Invoke-Command ... | Export-Csv ...`.

Comment: But what if I want to append it to an array? Later, I want to combine to  2 arrays.

Comment: @123testing123 - if you _send SOMETHING_ from the scriptblock & save that to a $Var, then you can do whatever you want with it later. [*grin*]

Comment: Like this? $array_otheruser += $obj
$var = $array_otheruser ... 
$var | Export-Csv -Path $CSVFile -NoTypeInformation But it doesn't work, I'm still getting an empty file.

Comment: @ Ansgar Wiechers, How do you output $obj in the scriptblock? Sorry, I'm not following. Could you please show me?

Comment: Remove `$array_otheruser += $obj` and change `$obj = $null` to just `$obj`.

Comment: So call $obj outside of Scriptblock? 
$obj | Export-Csv -Path "c:\temp\temp7.csv" -NoTypeInformation It is returning an error with Export-Csv : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
At line:70 char:8

Comment: That is not what I told you to do. Leave `$obj` *inside* the scriptblock, but remove the assignment operation. PowerShell's default action is to output stuff when it doesn't know what else to do with it (alternatively you can do `Write-Output $obj`, which does the same, just explicitly). Then do `Invoke-Command ... | Export-Csv`.